# MySQL root password automatically change ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, linux, azure

I have weird problem. My website is on windows azure platform on `Linux Server`. I am facing this issue since last month. Intermittently, root password gets change. And I couldn't login with root username and password. It's giving me below error.

> 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

I tried with  `mysql -u root` and  `mysql -u root -p`. It's not allowing me to login. I also checked `error.log` file. There is nothing in there.

I tried to check process:

```
ps -eaf | grep mysql
```

Result:

```
mysql     1484     1  0 Oct06 ?        00:42:31 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     54791 54760  0 15:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I don't know what to do in this situation. Only I have server access, and I am not running any background script that affects root password.

I have 2 questions here:

1) Why does root password get change automatically?

2) How can I get access to my database without root access?

**PS: I noticed that I am facing this problem since I separated OS disk and Data Disk on `azure`.**

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask Azure Support?

Comment: @u_mulder: I already opened a ticket there. They are investigating the problem. Right now they are saying that this is initiated by user (means from our side). I am afraid of hacking, that's why I asked the question here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your root password get change automatically. And there is no documents and evidence to show that separated OS disk and Data Disk can lead to root password changed on azure. If you want to change root password, I suggest you can [remote access](http://blogs.technet.com/b/uktechnet/archive/2013/11/12/running-a-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-azure-linux-vm.aspx) to your Linux VM and refer to [documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) to change password.

> 2) How can I get access to my database without root access?

If you'd like to access MySQL database without root access, you need set the empty password for your root accounts, however, we don't recommend it. You can see this reference about [MYSQL account permission](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html).